# DataReader em blocos using executam o "Close()" do DataReader?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Eu tenho uma pequena dúvida a respeito de DataReader's dentro de blocos using. Se o o meu objeto DataReader estiver dentro de um bloco using, ele será fechado ao final desse bloco? Ou eu tenho que inserir o método Close()?

Segue exemplo de DataReader com o bloco using:

```
using(var dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    //...Código
}
```

Está certo, ou eu tenho que inserir um Close()?

```
using(var dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    //...Código
    dr.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Estou assumindo que você se refere ao [`DbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou uma de suas subclasses (ex.: [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)), mas pode-se adaptar a resposta caso eu esteja engando.

Seu primeiro exemplo está correto, não há a necessidade de se inserir um `Close()`.

A função do comando [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) é garantir que todo [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) seja corretamente finalizado ao terminar o bloco - normalmente, ou através de uma exceção. Isso significa que será chamado o método `Dispose` do mesmo, se ele não for nulo é claro (i.e. se houver exceção durante sua criação, não há como finalizá-lo).

```
using(var dr = CriarDisposable()) {
    // código
}
```

É equivalente a:

```
{
  var dr = CriarDisposable();
  try
  {
    // Código
  }
  finally
  {
    if (dr != null)
      ((IDisposable)dr).Dispose();
  }
}
```

O `DbDataReader` implementa a interface `IDisposable`, e a documentação do seu método [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) diz:

> Libera os recursos usados pelo `DbDataReader` e chama `Close`.

Ou seja, não é necessário chamar `Close` manualmente, o próprio `using` se encarrega disso pra você.

P.S. Se eu me enganei, e você se refere a outra classe chamada `DataReader`, dê uma olhada na documentação se ela também implementa `IDisposable`, e o que o método `Dispose` faz.

Comment: É isso mesmo! No meu caso é o OracleDataReader, mas quiz ser um pouco genérico, pois o banco não influencia na pergunta. Obrigado @mgibsonbr!