# Como armazenar vários nomes de usuarios em uma variável?

Tags: c#, mysql

Eu tenho um *form*, e nele faço uma consulta no banco de dados:

```
private void Consulta()
{
  var dataCom = Convert.ToDateTime(label1.Text).ToShortDateString(); 

  var conf = $"select * from data where data_venc = '{Datacom}'";
  var comando = new MySqlCommand(conf, conn);

  conn.Open();

  var retorno = Convert.ToInt32(comando.ExecuteScalar());

  conn.Close();
}
```

A variavel `Datacom` recebe a data atual do sistema.

No banco de dados tenho duas datas (data do cadastro e data vencimento), ao fazer o cadastro usuário, acrescento 30 dias e salvo como data de vencimento.

Quero verificar se a data do vencimento é igual a do sistema, caso seja, guardo os nomes dos usuários em uma variável (ou sei lá ao do tipo) para que posso usar depois.

Após guardar esses nomes dessas variaveis, quero pegar cada nome para enviar emails cada um com seu nome.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Da forma como está seu código, ele não irá retornar os registros do banco de dados, apenas o total de registros afetados (`ExecuteScalar`).
Para retornar os registros, e posteriormente percorrê-los, você terá que utilizar o comando [`ExecuteReader`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/Overload_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlHelper_ExecuteReader.htm).

Como você quer armazenar em uma variável, basta utilizá-lo.
Modifiquei seu método para seja seja possível retornar os registros da sua *query*:

```
private MySqlDataReader Consulta(string connectionString) {
    MySqlDataReader retorno;

    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)) {


        var dataCom = Convert.ToDateTime(label1.Text).ToShortDateString();

        var conf = "select * from data where data_venc = @dataCom";
        conn.Open();

        using (var comando = new MySqlCommand(conf, conn)) {
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataCom", dataCom);

            retorno = comando.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Com esse método, você poderá criar então um laço para percorrer os registros, e com isso, enviar os e-mail como desejar.

```
while (Consulta("sua_string_conexao").Read()) {
    //Percorre o datareader - cara interação será um usuario que poderá enviar o email

}
```

Leituras recomendadas:

[É correto usar um bloco using dentro de outro bloco using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101535/46243)
[DataReader em blocos using executam o “Close()” do DataReader?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27787/46243)

Comment: bom, mas seu eu armazenar varios nomes em uma variavel poderei utilazar esses nomes separadamente para enviar um email para cada nomes desses separados?

Comment: @JuniorQuaresmaGutekoski, sim basta você criar um List<T> ou Array, no caso da forma que preferir. Depois percorrer esse objeto criado que no caso é uma lista ou um array e fazer o tratamento individual para cada nome que estiver nesse objeto. Ai é só disparar os e-mails

Comment: @JuniorQuaresmaGutekoski Olá, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.

Answer (score 0):

Criei um Array de objetos usuários e vá adicionando os usuários que estão expirados a ele.

Depois envie este array para a função que ira enviar o e-mail.

---

Direto a sua pergunta.

```
 ArrayList nomesExpirados = new ArrayList();

 nomesExpirados.add("nome cliente 1")

 nomesExpirados.add("nome cliente 2")
```

depois basta enviar este array nomesExpirados para a função de enviar e-mail.